# how to do inline validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

[image]
when I enter the name it will show "right symbol" beside the text-box. can you tel me it coding...may I do this type of validation using javascript

Comment: yes, you may... what have you tried so far?

Comment: what check has to be done for the validation ?

Comment: can you send me one example. I  tried to post the coding.. but showing some problem. please send me one coding example

Comment: how are u validating the firstname ?  is it special character, or you know how to validate and you just need to know how to show the tick on the side ?

Comment: Matt K can you send me it's coding

Comment: I did the validation but don't know how to show the tick on the side. if you know the answer please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this type of validation in Javascript. In fact one of the primary uses for Javascript was to do form validation. There are multiple ways to do it and there are even libraries and frameworks ([example](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml)) to do the form validation.

This is so common that some browsers have built-in validation algorithms (for example if `<input type="email">` complains if the contents of it doesn't look like an email address in latest Google Chrome).

If you want to do the validation, there are a couple of events that might be of your interest. `onblur` happens when the form element loses control. `onkeypress` happens as soon as user presses a key. There are other events as well. But usually you want to do the validation when user changes focus from the control to another one (`onblur`).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  Enter name then  press tab or click outside the input field:
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onblur="validate()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

And the `validate()` function can be something like this:

```
function validate()
{
  var val = document.getElementById("fname").value
  if ( /\d/.test( val ) ) {
    alert( "First name cannot have digits in it: " + val );
  }
}
```

You can search the net for more info.

Comment: If you know any link please share me this link.